# ORA-01425: escape character must be character string of length 1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

We are working a software working with .net (MVC) and Oracle database. After that, we were obliged to install a new version of Oracle (12.1.0) on the new server we face this error while searching while we didn't have such an error in version 12.2.0.
Error :

> ORA-01425: escape character must be a character string of length 1

My query is here

```
availableTasks.Where(task => task.Document.RegistrationNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord) || task.WorkflowNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord) || task.Description.Contains(searchkeyWord));
```

it is worth mentioning that when I remove `task.Document.RegistrationNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord)` or `task.WorkflowNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord) || task.Description.Contains(searchkeyWord)` it works perfectly.

My query output from Linq:

```
SELECT 
"GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1"
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS "A1"
    FROM   (SELECT "Extent1"."Id" AS "Id1", "Extent1"."Document_Id" AS "Document_Id", "Extent1"."Member_Id" AS "Member_Id", "Extent1"."Command_Id" AS "Command_Id", "Extent1"."InitialTask_Id" AS "InitialTask_Id", "Extent1"."Sender_Id" AS "Sender_Id", "Extent1"."Receiver_Id" AS "Receiver_Id", "Extent1"."Department_Id" AS "Department_Id", "Extent1"."PreviousTask_Id" AS "PreviousTask_Id", "Extent1"."OpeningTime" AS "OpeningTime", "Extent1"."ClosingTime" AS "ClosingTime", "Extent1"."IsDone" AS "IsDone", "Extent1"."Description" AS "Description", "Extent1"."MetaData" AS "MetaData", "Extent1"."WorkflowNumber" AS "WorkflowNumber", "Extent1"."Comment" AS "Comment", "Extent2"."Id" AS "Id2", "Extent2"."PortCommunity_Id" AS "PortCommunity_Id", "Extent2"."Accessibility_Id" AS "Accessibility_Id", "Extent2"."IssuedUser_Id" AS "IssuedUser_Id", "Extent2"."ChangingTime" AS "ChangingTime", "Extent2"."RegistrationNumber" AS "RegistrationNumber", "Extent2"."RegistrationDate" AS "RegistrationDate", "Extent2"."SequenceNumber" AS "SequenceNumber", "Extent2"."DocumentStatus" AS "DocumentStatus", "Extent2"."DocumentType" AS "DocumentType"
        FROM  "KISH"."Task" "Extent1"
        INNER JOIN "KISH"."Document" "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."Document_Id" = "Extent2"."Id"
        WHERE ("Extent1"."IsDone" <> 1) ) "Filter1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "KISH"."User" "Extent3" ON "Filter1"."Receiver_Id" = "Extent3"."Id"
    WHERE (((("Filter1"."Member_Id" = :p__linq__0) AND ("Filter1"."Command_Id" = :p__linq__1)) OR ("Filter1"."Command_Id" <> :p__linq__2)) AND ("Filter1"."PortCommunity_Id" = :p__linq__3) AND ((:p__linq__4 <> 1) OR ("Filter1"."Receiver_Id" IS NULL) OR ("Filter1"."Receiver_Id" = :p__linq__5)) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS "C1"
        FROM "KISH"."Permission" "Extent4"
        WHERE (("Extent4"."User_Id" = :p__linq__6) AND ("Extent4"."Member_Id" = :p__linq__7) AND ("Extent4"."PortCommunity_Id" = :p__linq__8) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS "C1"
            FROM "KISH"."RoleCommand" "Extent5"
            WHERE (("Extent4"."Role_Id" = "Extent5"."Role_Id") AND ("Extent5"."Command_Id" = "Filter1"."Command_Id"))
        )) AND (("Extent4"."Department_Id" IS NULL) OR ("Filter1"."Department_Id" IS NULL) OR ("Extent4"."Department_Id" = "Filter1"."Department_Id") OR (("Extent4"."Department_Id" IS NULL) AND ("Filter1"."Department_Id" IS NULL))))
    )) AND (("Filter1"."RegistrationNumber" LIKE :p__linq__9 ESCAPE '\') OR ("Filter1"."WorkflowNumber" LIKE :p__linq__10 ESCAPE '\') OR ("Filter1"."Description" LIKE :p__linq__11 ESCAPE '\')))
)  "GroupBy1"SQL: 
SQL: -- p__linq__0: 'db717061-06f1-4235-8413-1d76f65ba80f' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__1: '19ccc777-634f-43c6-a5d3-037ae78be91c' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__2: '19ccc777-634f-43c6-a5d3-037ae78be91c' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__3: '04922971-1ea5-4f76-8de6-13b6e460364b' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__4: 'True' (Type = Decimal, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__5: '1d0c0570-9dd0-4aa4-92d7-8055b567c351' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__6: '1d0c0570-9dd0-4aa4-92d7-8055b567c351' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__7: 'db717061-06f1-4235-8413-1d76f65ba80f' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__8: '04922971-1ea5-4f76-8de6-13b6e460364b' (Type = Binary, IsNullable = false)
SQL: -- p__linq__9: '%30%' (Type = Object)
SQL: -- p__linq__10: '%30%' (Type = Object)
SQL: -- p__linq__11: '%30%' (Type = Object)
```

I am completely confused by this problem. I don't know if it is for a different Oracle version or something else.

Comment: I assumed you're using EF with Oracle provider, can you provide generated Oracle SQL query generated by the LINQ statement (of course it contains `ESCAPE` statement as the message pointed)?

Comment: Yes I'm using EF

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto - I put sql code

Comment: Try using `Trim()`: `availableTasks.Where(task => task.Document.RegistrationNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord.Trim()) || task.WorkflowNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord.Trim()) || task.Description.Contains(searchkeyWord.Trim()));`. This should generate `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` which avoiding usage of `ESCAPE '\'` where the problem originated from.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto - Thank u man it works

Comment: Put post in order to vote it. Like!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of `Contains()` method in LINQ with Entity Framework ODP seems not working properly when handling `System.String` argument directly in certain situations, it will generate `LIKE` with `ESCAPE '\'` statement in PL/SQL query which will throw ORA-01425 error (as shown in [similar issue here](http://blog.darkthread.net/post-2015-05-09-ora-01425-error-in-linq-contains-query.aspx)). To mitigate this behavior, just use `Trim()` inside `Contains()` method against string argument:

```
availableTasks.Where(task => task.Document.RegistrationNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord.Trim()) 
                     || task.WorkflowNumber.Contains(searchkeyWord.Trim()) 
                     || task.Description.Contains(searchkeyWord.Trim()));
```

The `Trim()` method will generate [`INSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) and `TRIM` statements (or `LTRIM`-`RTRIM` pairs) as replacement of `LIKE` with `ESCAPE` statements, as in example below:

```
SELECT <snip> FROM <snip> WHERE [condition] AND ((NVL(INSTR("Filter1"."RegistrationNumber", TRIM(:p__linq__9)), 0)) > 0) 
OR ((NVL(INSTR("Filter1"."WorkflowNumber", TRIM(:p__linq__10)), 0)) > 0)
OR ((NVL(INSTR("Filter1"."Description", TRIM(:p__linq__11)), 0)) > 0)
```

By implementing `INSTR` with `TRIM`, the query will run smoothly when handling LINQ generated parameters (`:p__linq__XX`) containing `System.String` value.

Comment: The Trim() method also worked for me as using Contains() within an Any() was throwing ora-01425

Answer (score 1):

The `ESCAPE` in the SQL statement you posted is fine - `ESCAPE '\'`

But this is the query text logged by *LINQ*

The best way to see the real query statement send to DB is to activate a **10046 trace**.

```
 ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = escape;
 alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';
```

in your connection and run the statement.

You will find a file such as xxx_ora_NNNN_ESCAPE.trc in the trace folde of the DB Server.

I suspect you will see a statement using something like

```
escape '\\'
```

Comment: I dont have any problem with Oracle (12.1.0). This problem occured when I change to 12.2.0 . I think it needs to some setting in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem

Resolved by changing parameter `CURSOR_SHARING` to `EXACT`

Answer (score 0):

select emp.emp_id from employee emp where  emp.NAME like '%\\_%' ESCAPE '\\';